# Jython Error : [ERROR] Failed to construct terminal; falling back to unsupported

Tags: java, python, macos, jython, macos-mojave

I wrote a Jython program and it worked perfectly
After(I do not know what happened) I ran the code and jython gives me this output:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.python.core.PySystemState (file:/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.7.1/libexec/jython.jar) to method java.io.Console.encoding()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.python.core.PySystemState
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[ERROR] Failed to construct terminal; falling back to unsupported
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0x100"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:983)
    at org.python.jline.internal.InfoCmp.parseInfoCmp(InfoCmp.java:59)
    at org.python.jline.UnixTerminal.parseInfoCmp(UnixTerminal.java:242)
    at org.python.jline.UnixTerminal.<init>(UnixTerminal.java:65)
    at org.python.jline.UnixTerminal.<init>(UnixTerminal.java:50)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584)
    at org.python.jline.TerminalFactory.getFlavor(TerminalFactory.java:211)
    at org.python.jline.TerminalFactory.create(TerminalFactory.java:102)
    at org.python.jline.TerminalFactory.get(TerminalFactory.java:186)
    at org.python.jline.TerminalFactory.get(TerminalFactory.java:192)
    at org.python.jline.console.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:243)
    at org.python.util.JLineConsole.install(JLineConsole.java:107)
    at org.python.core.Py.installConsole(Py.java:1744)
    at org.python.core.PySystemState.initConsole(PySystemState.java:1269)
    at org.python.core.PySystemState.doInitialize(PySystemState.java:1119)
    at org.python.core.PySystemState.initialize(PySystemState.java:1033)
    at org.python.core.PySystemState.initialize(PySystemState.java:989)
    at org.python.core.PySystemState.initialize(PySystemState.java:984)
    at org.python.util.jython.run(jython.java:263)
    at org.python.util.jython.main(jython.java:142)
```

it still gives me this output and nothing happens. I tried to reinstall jython but it still gives me the error. I tried to run other jython programs and i still get the error.

Thanks

I have a MacOs X Mojave

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: It appears to be a bug with Jline. I'd submit an official Jython bug report with links to https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1565725 and https://github.com/jline/jline2/issues/281. They need to update their jline version. This only happened recently because of the updates to the 1.8 JDK.